# why csv export not working?

Tags: symfony, export-to-csv

I try to do a csv export on my symfony project and i think that something is wrong because the function return a simple response and don't download the csv.

here is the function:

```
public function exportCsv($customers)
{

    $fileName = "export_" . date("d_m_Y") . ".csv";
    $response = new StreamedResponse();

        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

        fputcsv($handle, array('Name',
            'Adress',
            'City',
            'Code'
        ), ';');


        foreach ($customers as $index => $custom)
        {

            fputcsv($handle,array(
                $custom->getName(),
                $custom->getAdress(),
                $custom->getCity(),
                $client->getCode(),
            ),';');
        }

        fclose($handle);

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.$fileName);

    return $response;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a streamed response object, you needed to add the callback function that will fill out your response object with content: `$response->setCallback()`.

```
public function exportCsv($customers)
{

    $fileName = "export_" . date("d_m_Y") . ".csv";
    $response = new StreamedResponse();


    $response->setCallback(function() {
      $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

      fputcsv($handle, array('Name', 'Adress', 'City', 'Code'),';');

      foreach ($customers as $index => $custom)
      {

          fputcsv($handle,array(
              $custom->getName(),
              $custom->getAdress(),
              $custom->getCity(),
              $client->getCode(),
          ),';');
      }

      fclose($handle);
    });

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; 
    filename='.$fileName);

    return $response;

}
```

Comment: Ok! Thank you for your answer!! but it doesnt work.. I add this line: $response->setCallback(function() use ($customers){}); And now i have no response... Any Idea?? Maybe i forgot headers???